# javers, Spring Boot, PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, javers

How to configure Javers with Spring Boot 2.x and Postgresql such that javers tables are created in a specific schema (named dbo) rather than the default "public" schema of the database?

Comment: I tried it with the following Spring Boot application.properties config and the javers tables are still being created in the default "public" schema:                                          
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://aafb2lf6edxu73.cjdfdq29dob4.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/PSSV2Db
spring.datasource.username=pss
spring.datasource.password=********
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo

Answer (score 0):

I have created the issue for that:

https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/690

Consider contributing a PR, it's really easy to implement this props.